# What should I do if the plastic waterline connection on my dishwasher is stripped?

Tags: plumbing, water, dishwasher

I'm a first-time homeowner and just bought a new dishwasher. I've repaired my car in the past using manuals just fine so thought I'd give home device installation a try.

Things were going great until I tried to connect the waterline to the dishwasher. The waterline connection on the dishwasher has plastic threads, and it did not like the metal waterline very much. It got stripped pretty badly when I tried to screw them together, and I no longer can get the damn thing on straight. It's a lost cause.

I'm worried I damaged that part to the dishwasher and more or less defected the whole dishwasher. But maybe I can cut off the stripped screw lines on the plastic end and use some of the fresh threads above it? What exactly am I supposed to do? Should I just let a plumber fix this?

The connection that got stripped is the blue thing below, and the waterline is dripping into a bowl (not sure if that is a good thing, might need to replace stop valve)
[image]

[image]

Comment: It would help if you could give the make and model number.  Photos of the damaged part and the back of the machine (where the hose connects) would also help. On many appliances, replacing the hookup hoses is either very simple or, in some situations might require opening up the appliance and using manufacturer replacement parts.

Comment: Evey DW I've ever installed has a brass elbow on it's water inlet. Use two wrenches, one to back-up the valve, so you don't break it, and one to remove the elbow. If you don't see the fitting like that, hit us with the model number. Sounds like you tried screwing a line with machine/tapered thread onto a pipe with NPT (national pipe thread). I surmise that there is no valve on the pipe or it would have gone fine (which there should be).

Comment: Here is the dishwasher I ordered. I'll see if I can update with some pictures of the damage. I just called the plumber too, he's coming tomorrow. http://www.homedepot.com/p/Whirlpool-Front-Control-Dishwasher-in-Monochromatic-Stainless-Steel-WDF520PADM/205506225

Comment: Did I assemble this backwards? Was I supposed to put the elbow on first and then hook the waterline?

Comment: A valve that leaks a little when a pipes open doesn't necessarily need to be replaced; only if it leaks somewhere once it's all hooked-up. Definitely take the elbow off and try again. Lay it down to work on it and get that fitting on first.

Comment: I was wondering about that... maybe it would he all right once it was hooked up... until I noticed a leak at the knob too.

Comment: You might be able to tighten a nut on the valve to stop that. It may also stop once turned back on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The blue plastic piece itself can't be replaced. The whole inlet valve needs to be replaced. Pretty sure it's [this part](http://www.appliancepartspros.com/whirlpool-valve-inlt-w10327250-ap5804368.html) which costs about $50. Not very familiar with taking apart dishwashers down that far but the appliances I have taken apart have been surprisingly easy. I've always found videos online that helped. This video looks like your dishwasher. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNMd_lDdG_w looks very easy... but then again so does screwing in a supply hose. :)

Considering it's a new appliance and your inexperience with repairing dishwashers you may want to call Whirlpool. It may even be covered under warranty.

Very surprised to see that it's made of plastic.

Comment: Not quite sure what to do... I got a leaky stop valve under the sink, a dishwasher with a stripped inlet, and  a plumber coming tomorrow promising to fix it all for $160. I could call Whirlpool or Home Depot and try to claim the warranty, only to have it fixed several days from now, and fix the stop valve myself. Or just walk away from all of it and let the plumber fix it tomorrow. Decisions, decisions...

Comment: Yeah when I saw the plastic that really ticked me off. That was a bad material choice for something connecting to metal.

Comment: @ThomasN. Not familiar with your area but that seems like a decent rate to me. Probably best way to go considering you need the stop valve replaced too.

Comment: @ThomasN. I've done the same on a fridge once. Plastic threads can be difficult to line up because you can't feel it cross threading as readily. Take the elbow off and give it another go, if you're OK with messing it up past the point the plumber might have had no problem with. We could prob help with that valve, too... But I agree with OG, it's not a bad price, however both are easily within the realm of DIY if you are comfortable.

Comment: Yeah, I'm kind of tired and running out of time before Monday comes. If I had a few days to mess around I would, but I have things to do tomorrow so I'm going to let the plumber do this. This was a great learning experience though, and I appreciate all your guys' help. I will let you all know what happens tomorrow.

Comment: @ThomasN. Plan change the stop valve whenever doing most plumbing projects. They go unused for years and then when you finally shut them off they leak or break. Been replacing with 1/4 turn ball valves instead. Must be something about dishwashers too. Replaced mine a few months ago. Spent the better part of the day running back and forth to the hw store kept getting wrong parts. Forgot to get stop valve too. Got a call the following week from the company contracted to do the installation. Doh! Didn't know. Took apart a dryer to make it fit in door and it took less time to install.

Comment: Yeah I heard about that, and in hindsight I wish I got stop valves for the whole kitchen before attempting this. They sound like one of those things that break when you need them the most.

Comment: Plumber came today. He fixed everything with no issues. He said the inlet was very difficult but he was able to screw the elbow on straight despite the stripping. Had to pay about $200 since I didn't tell him about leaky stop valve. But overall it was worth it to protect my hardwood floors from disaster. He also highlighted that my drain hose was too low and needs to come from above, not below. I think I could have done this but I dont really want to mess around with plumbing again. Water is a scary thing to mess up.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem! Saw your pic and it exactly like mine-plastic piece on dishwasher and you have to add a metal elbow. They don't marry well. After several futile tries, and reading what happened here, I think the plastic wasn't stripped-it just doesn't match well. So I took the elbow off the hose (much easier to manage) and wrapped a bunch of plumbers tape around the blue plastic female part. I then started attaching the metal elbow by hand, and moving with a wrench. I kept on tightening it until it was almost to the top,and wouldn't move any further. Then I attached the hose to the other end of the elbow. No leaks!!! I think the plumbers tape did the trick. I had put that thing on and off several times before looking for other solutions.

Answer (score 3):

If I was doing it over again I would have assembled the elbow to the inlet valve before installing dishwasher.everything exposed and easier to make connection without crossthreading. Now that I already crossthreaded the conn this worked for me.I disconnected everything and moved the dishwasher out so I had easy access to valve. Removed valve. Took a hacksaw and cut off 2 or 3 threads. Installed elbow.worked perfectly.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone, here is what worked for me. I had tried two or three times to tighten the elbow piece into the blue plastic. But even as I was getting it tight with a wrench, it looked like it was not turned in enough. So the next time I made a conscious effort to push the piece up when I started threading; it did go up more turns before it got tight, and tightened it a bit more with the wrench, and it's not leaking now.

Answer (score 1):

Our new Whirlpool dishwasher came with damaged threads on the blue plastic connector. I had success using an oscillating saw to carefully remove the two damaged threads which thankfully were on the bottom end of the connector. I used a small sharp knife and sandpaper to remove burrs though the oscillating saw left few. If installing a new dishwasher it is best to just place the machine on its back and install the L-shaped brass fitting to the blue connector first using appropriate Teflon tape or pipe joint compound. You must apply pressure to the large brass portion of the L-shaped fitting as you turn it clockwise to screw it onto the blue connector. Make sure the black washer inside the L-shaped fitting is in place and not twisted. Do not over tighten. Of course, you must be careful not to damage the L-shaped fitting when you move the dishwasher into position.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this seems to be a common occurrence.  I had exactly the same problem.  I had to put the thing on the belt sander to remove about an 1/8th of an inch of plastic.  I had to completely remove the plastic piece and then I was able to put it on correctly.  I have also ordered the spare part which is 17 bucks on Amazon.  I'll swap it out later...  Good luck if you have this issue.  Whirlpool needs to rethink this part or include the adapter that is required.